# Flutter hot reload on save not working anymore

Tags: flutter, dart

recently updated flutter to latest sdk and vs code as well auto-updated itself. after that ho reload not working anymore. not sure the issue is with the vs code or flutter itself.

Comment: It may be related to your IDE not sending the 'hot reload' command after the save while running the app. try running the app through the CLI and hit 'r' after your changes to see if it is picking the changes or not. if not then it sounds like and issue with Flutter. if it does pick the updates then it is an issue with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the issue is related to flutter sdk, you can get back to the previous version with :

```
flutter downgrade
```

in the command line